# MongoDB´s automatically cast int32 in a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express

We have built an Express API with MongoDB. On a route, we return all our documents from the collection.

The mongoose Schema is set up like this

```
videoCount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    trim: 
}
```

Robo 3T form a single document
[image: Robo 3T]

On a request to our API endpoint, the `videoCount` is returned as a String and not as expected Int32

Returned JSON

```
    {
        "_id": "5c1bab4871741d63ffc94a37",
        "thumbnail": "some url",
        "categorie": "data",
        "videoCount": "17032",
        "__v": 0
    }...
```

We get the response with the `find()` method and simply response all the results back to the client.

Is there any config that we have to add for getting the `videoCount` as Int?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I have now fixed this problem. Just install the node module body-parser and use it as an express middleware

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
```